# Hiding multivalue data leaving (Select All) in the dropdown

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a multivalue drop down parameter called State ((Select All), California, Hawaii, Nevada, Illinois etc. etc ).  Is there a way to hide the data leaving the (Select All) as the only selection in the parameter?

Comment: Why have a parameter if you're going to select all only?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new parameter and specify values, Label is as Select all and enter the values you want into the value field separated by commas.

[image: Parameter Select All]

[image: Param Select All]